# Swift Package Manager Not Installing

Tags: swift, toolchain, swift-package-manager

So if you navigate [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager#installing), you'll find instructions saying that the package manager is bundled in the downloads on [this page.](https://swift.org/download/)

It says that I can check with:

> swift build --help

But my only output has been:

> :0: error: no such file or directory: 'build'

I have downloaded both installation packages and installed them.  I can see that the toolchains are installed here.  (I also installed the previous version out of desperation).

[image: installed toolchain]

The instructions aren't very explicit and in a world of all in one IDE's, I haven't yet experienced installing a language of my own in this way.  Is there something obvious I'm missing in the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the PATH environment variable setup to map to the correct Swift?

`swift --version` should show

```
Apple Swift version 2.2-dev (LLVM 46be9ff861, Clang 4deb154edc, Swift 778f82939c)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9
```

If you are running a Swift version prior to 2.2, then you need to set your path to the new toolchain installed by the Swift 2.2 snapshot. This can be done by editing your `.bash_profile` and adding

`export PATH=/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-latest.xctoolchain/usr/bin:$PATH`

as the last line and then `source ~/.bash_profile` to update your settings.

**Edit**

On December 10, 2015 there was a new snapshot released. `--version` still shows `2.2-dev` but shows updated (SHA-1?) hashes.

```
Apple Swift version 2.2-dev (LLVM 7bae82deaa, Clang 53d04af5ce, Swift 5995ef2acd)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9
```

These releases are also tagged at the individual project level as a release: https://github.com/apple/swift/releases

Comment: Possibly not, here's my print out on a `swift --version` command.  `Apple Swift version 2.1.1 (swiftlang-700.1.101.15 clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0`

Comment: That is the swift version that comes with Xcode 7. I would revisit your PATH settings. Something like this as the last line in your `.bash_profile` should work. `export PATH=/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-latest.xctoolchain/usr/bin:$PATH`

Comment: For whatever reason, I thought that applied to a different scenario and didn't matter if you weren't using Xcode. Thanks!

Comment: One final thing, could you update your answer to include your last comment in case others make it here in the future.

Comment: Ok. I've added the extra detail.